# how to extract a separate JSON file's data to create a google line chart?

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts, google-visualization

I have a JSON file:

```
[{"date": "2014-01-01","value": 190000000},{"date": "2014-01-02","value": 190379978},{"date": "2014-01-03","value": 90493749},{"date": "2014-01-04","value": 190785250}]
```

It can be extendable. I want to create a google line chart by extracting the JSON data by using following codes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});      
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(line_chart);
function line_chart()
  {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: 'getdata.php',
        dataType:"json",
        async: false,
        success: function(jsonData)
         {
            var options =
            {
               legend: 'none',
               hAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 30 },
               curveType: 'function',
               pointSize: 7,
               dataOpacity: 0.3
            };
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
                     chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 400});                     
         }  
       }).responseText;      
  }
</script>
```

my getdata.php code is:

```
<?php 
print test();
function test() {
    $jsonurl = 'data.json';
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
    echo $obj;
}
?>
```

during getdata.php all JSON data are dumped in an array. but the chart is not formed. How can i create the line chart? whats the problem in my code? Please help.

Comment: Why would you use `var_dump()`? The result is invalid json, just echo the `$json` variable directly.

Comment: @jeroen... I was trying without using var_dump() too. But it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

when loading google data table using `arrayToDataTable`

the array must be a simple array with the values, no generic objects, e.g.

```
[["2014-01-01", 190000000], ["2014-01-02", 190379978], ...]
```

if using json, then it must be in [google's specific json format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

this would work too...

```
[[{v: "2014-01-01"}, {v: 190000000}], [{v: "2014-01-02"}, {v: 190379978}], ...]
```

---

as such, if the data in the question cannot be changed to match,
then a simple routine to transform the data for google is required

see following working snippet, the data is hard-coded in the `fail` callback,
since `'getdata.php'` isn't available from here

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: line_chart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function line_chart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getdata.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(
    draw_chart
  ).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    //console.log(textStatus);

    // for testing json data, remove when getdata.php is available
    draw_chart([{"date": "2014-01-01","value": 190000000},{"date": "2014-01-02","value": 190379978},{"date": "2014-01-03","value": 90493749},{"date": "2014-01-04","value": 190785250}]);
  });

  function draw_chart(jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    $.each(jsonData, function (i, row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.date,
        row.value
      ]);
    });

    var options = {
      legend: 'none',
      hAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 30
      },
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 7,
      dataOpacity: 0.3,
      width: 600,
      height: 400
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="linechart_div"></div>
```